# Show bundle product options in list/grid view - Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

This question is about Magento bundled products:
I want to add the bundle product customization section to list/grid view without going into a separate customization form. Could you please anyone can give me a solution to do this?

I tried below method:

1. Added below section to catalog.xml
   `<block type="bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle" name="product.list.bundle.options" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/options.phtml">
                       <action method="addRenderer"><type>select</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select</block></action>
                       <action method="addRenderer"><type>multi</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_multi</block></action>
                       <action method="addRenderer"><type>radio</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio</block></action>
                       <action method="addRenderer"><type>checkbox</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox</block></action>
                   </block>`
2. Added below code to listing.phtml

`<?php if($_product->getTypeId() == "bundle"){

            echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.list.bundle.options')->setProduct($_product)->toHtml();
    }
    ?>`

but it didn't work.